# Submit Button to Populate On page text

Tags: html, forms, populate

I am looking for a way that I can create custom text on an HTML page dependent on user input from a submit form. I've looked at similar threads online but can't figure out how to do this on my own page.

Basically I have a text area with this default text "My name is  and I want to give $10 to charity".

If I have a submit form button how do I get it to take the name entered from the form and then put that value in to the  portion of the text?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/NbuF6/2/

Basically, you have a textarea (id: final-text) and an input (id: name). The button (this can be changed to the form's onsubmit function if you want to) calls the following JavaScript function to fill the textarea:

```
function fill_textarea() {
    document.getElementById('final-text').value = 'My name is ' + document.getElementById('name').value + ' and I want to give $10 to charity';
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,

How do I set up the HTML to work with this function?

Looking at using something like this:

   <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
   Username: <input type="text" name="user">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form> 

From here:

   http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle code to match yours. Now, before the form submits, it fills the textarea.
I am not sure what you are using this for, but you might want to replace the textarea with a hidden input. Even better would be to do this server side..

Comment: Thanks again for your effort to help me, appreciate it. I am a good bit clearer on doing this now and what you have given I should be able to make that work for me. 

I've never seen how to do that server side, is the code much different?

Comment: It depends on your needs. If all you want to do, is to show the text on the screen, the server side part will not be that hard :)

Comment: would you be willing to share how to do that - more out of interest to see the workings - I suppose I am quite curious!

Comment: As I see your form posts to an ASP file, you can do that like this:
    <% Response.Write("My name is " & Request.Form("name") & " and I want to give $10 to charity.") %>